# Can we use our sewing machine in Europe

Tags: voltage

We have a Singer 1507 sewing machine. The instructions say, "The foot control must be unes with the appliance by KD-1902 (110-120V area) / KD-2902 (220-240V area) manufactured by ZHEJIANG FOUNDER MOTOR CORPORATION LTD. (China) 4C-316B (110-125V area) / 4C-326G (230 V area) maufactured by Wakaho Electric Ind. Co,. Ltd (Vietnam).

Does this mean I can purchase a new plug and use my machine in Europe?

Comment: Consumer electronics are not on topic for our site, instead we focus on the design of such electronics.

Answer (score 2):

From your quote I understand that it depends on whether you have a KD-1902 (=> no) or a KD-2902 (=> yes).

---

**Added - RM:**

You do not say what country you are in or what your mains voltage is.
 The two main choices are "around 100 VAC" and "around 230 VAC".
 The KD2902 machine will operate on voltages around 230 VAC.
 The KD1902  machine will operate on voltages around 110 VAC.
 The two are not interchangeable by simply changing the plug.

IF your local power supply is in the 210 VAC to 240 VAC range then you can probably use the machine in Europe.

IF your local power supply is in the 110 VAC to 120 VAC range then you can probably NOT use the machine in Europe.

A 110VAC rate machine can be used on 230 VAC with a suitably rated 230 to 110 VAC transformer but the cost of this may make it not worthwhile.

---

What country are you in?
 What is your local mains voltage.